# Android - OAuth 1.0a callback -> data android:scheme does not work, because service provider only allows http or https

Tags: java, android, oauth, intentfilter

I have an Android application with OAuth 1.0a authentication. The web browser is used, so that the user can authenticate against the service provider.

I can provide a callback URL, which will be called when the user authorization was successful. I used as callback URL: `mytestapp://www.test.com/`.

And then I can do this in my AndroidManifest inside the `intent-filter`:

```
<data android:scheme="mytestapp"></data>
```

So this activity will be called, because of the `mytestapp` scheme.
But my problem is, that the service provider only allows `http://` or `https://` and it won't fire up this activity of my app.

So what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, that I use `android:scheme`, `android:host` and `android:pathPrefix`.
Unfortunately, the callback will display me if I want to use the browser or my application and I have to select it manually.